# how many bit strings containing exactly eight 0s and twelve 1s have either all the 0s consecutive or all the 1s consecutive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hi all was struggling with this question, hoping someone can help me out.

1. how many bit strings containing exactly eight 0's and twelve 1's have either all the 0's consecutive, or all the 1's consecutive?

what approach/ principle or theory should i be using?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: I would try counting them...

Answer (score 1):

Group the zeroes together and now imagine you have 1 zero and 12 ones. You can make $13$ distinct numbers. Now just "expand" the stacked zeroes. Similar reasoning yields $9$ different numbers when the ones are together. But note that we counted $11111111111100000000$ and $00000000111111111111$ twice.

Therefore the total number is $20$.

Comment: You are counting $1^{12}0^8$ (and the opposite) twice.

Comment: @lulu Nice observation! I will edit my answer now

Answer (score 0):

For this question, we can count them up in a rather straightforward manner. Let's look at the strings with 12 ones. We can organize our list by which position the consecutive ones will start in:
$$11111111111100000000$$
through
$$00000000111111111111.$$
Note that our run of ones can occur in positions 1-12 through 9-20 for 9 possibilites.

A similar bit of counting can find where a run of zeroes occurs: positions 1-8 through 13-20 for 13 possibilites.

**However**, there will be two repeated strings that satisfy both conditions! Namely, they are the two listed examples above. Not wanting to double count, we can't simply add our number of possibilities together. Recall that, using $card (A)$ to denote the cardinality of set $A$ (the number of elements), 
$$card (A \cup B) = card (A) + card (B) - card (A \cap B).$$

Thus our answer is $9+ 13 -2 = 20$ possibilites.